# data and params in onDocumentCreated Firebase function are undefined when called from firebase-functions-test

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js

I've written a very simple test function currently only logging data and params in my functions `index.ts`:

```ts
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'
import { onDocumentCreated } from 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore'

initializeApp()

exports.onNewSale = onDocumentCreated('customers/{customerId}/sales/{saleId}', (event) => {
  console.log('params', event.params)
  console.log('data', event.data?.data())
})
```

When I'm triggering the function in the emulator by creating a document I get the correct logging:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-onNewSale"
>  params { customerId: '3s2dwWr2QdmmZlze788Z', saleId: '62OUh9iqX0BmONfVCohJ' }
>  data { foo: 'bar' }
```

But when I'm testing the function using firebase-function-test and mocha, data is undefined and params is an empty object:

```
$ mocha --require ts-node/register --reporter spec


  onNewSale
    execution
params {}
data undefined
      ✔ should execute


  1 passing (6ms)

✨  Done in 1.56s.
```

Here's what my `index.test.js` looks like:

```js
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')(
  {
    databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'my-project',
    storageBucket: 'my-project.appspot.com'
  },
  'serviceAccountKey.json'
)

const { onNewSale } = require('../src/index.ts')

describe('onNewSale', function () {
  describe('execution', function () {
    it('should execute', function (done) {
      const data = test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot({ foo: 'bar' })

      const params = {
        customerId: '3s2dwWr2QdmmZlze788Z',
        saleId: '62OUh9iqX0BmONfVCohJ'
      }

      const wrapped = test.wrap(onNewSale)

      wrapped(data, { params })

      done()
    })
  })
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out that `firebase-functions-test` doesn't support 2nd gen Firebase Cloud Functions yet. At least not all types.

Comment: Could you please add a source to this information? I am having the exact same probem :/ Any idea how to find a workaround? Use 1st gen?

Comment: @molundb I found some [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/issues) and tested it by myself. As soon as I downgraded to 1st gen, everything worked out fine. So right now sticking with 1st gen is my workaround.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I figured out a way to solve it with 2nd gen functions, please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77318314/2225594.

Answer (score 3):

This structure works in my test in Typescript with 2nd gen functions.

```
it('should execute', function (done) {
  const data = test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot({ foo: 'bar' })

  const params = {
    customerId: '3s2dwWr2QdmmZlze788Z',
    saleId: '62OUh9iqX0BmONfVCohJ'
  }

  event = { data: data, params: params };

  const wrapped = test.wrap(onNewSale)
  wrapped(event)

  done()
})
```

It's based on this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/issues/205