# Can't get parameters in v2 function with firebase-functions-test

Tags: javascript, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js

I have a v2 onCall function:

```
import { HttpsError, onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import { logger } from "firebase-functions";
import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth";

const createAccount = onCall((request) => {
    return getAuth()
        .createUser({
            email: request.data.email,
            emailVerified: false,
            password: request.data.password,
            disabled: false,
        })
        .then((user) => {
            logger.log(`Successfully created new user ${user.uid} (${request.data.email})`);
            return `Successfully created new user ${request.data.email}`;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Error handling (long code withheld)...
        });
});
```

And I'm testing it with `firebase-functions-test` with mocha (`mocha --reporter spec`), as [the docs specify](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#constructing_test_data):

```
it('Should complete', (done) => {

    const data = test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot({ email: "test@test.com", password: "password12345" }, 'test/123');

    const wrapped = test.wrap(functions.createAccount);
    wrapped(data);

    done();
})
```

**This runs fine**, completes without an error and creates a new user account. But on the console, I noticed it kept creating anonymous accounts. Turns out the function wasn't getting the parameters, so I added the following code to the beginning of the onCall function:

```
if (!request.data.email) {
    throw new HttpsError('invalid-argument', "Must provide an email");
}
if (!request.data.password) {
    throw new HttpsError('invalid-argument', "Must provide a password");
}
```

And it keeps throwing an error because `request.data.email` is not defined. I've tried every option I could find (change document path, change input to an object, added the 'params' object to options, stringifying the input, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77318314/12303271) example), but `request.data` never has the parameters I specify. How can I properly add parameters?

My config files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.11.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsx": "^4.7.0",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

.mocharc.json

```
{
  "extensions": ["ts"],
  "spec": ["test/**/*.ts"],
  "node-option": [
    "experimental-specifier-resolution=node",
    "import=tsx/esm"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Would you please post the code from the client where the function is called?

Comment: @trndjc The second code block I posted is where it's being called (in a test file). All that file has beside it is setup code for the test framework which works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `firebase-functions-test` doesn't support v2 functions yet and just treats them like v1 functions. The parameters are still passed, but you need to access the "private" `_fieldsproto` field:

```
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

const createAccount = onCall((request) => {

    const email = request.data.email ?? request._fieldsProto.email.stringValue;

    // ...
}
```

Since this requires editing the production code for the sake of testing, I'd recommend using v1 functions instead