# Firebase Function V2... Access secrets with latest versions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Current code is working but in the console its showing the version is 1...
How do i make it so that it becomes **latest**

```
exports.onUserCreate = onDocumentCreated(
  {
    memory: "1GiB",
    document: "users/{id}",
    secrets: ["notification_email", "notification_password"],
  },
  async (event) => {
    //...
  }
```

[image]

I can manually update it to the latest but how do i do it in the code
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in "[Extend Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions (2nd gen)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen)" or "[Cloud Functions version comparison](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/version-comparison)" would explain the behavior of how secrets are managed or how the latest version of a secret is used.

A common pattern in cloud services is that, when a resource identifier without a version number is provided, the latest version is assumed.
That is to make sure systems are using the most recent, and therefore likely the most secure and up-to-date, configurations.

The "Extend Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions (2nd gen)" page does not explicitly mention the behavior of how secrets are managed or how the latest version of a secret is used. However, it is a common pattern in cloud services that when a resource identifier without a version number is provided, the latest version is assumed. That is to make sure systems are using the most recent, and therefore likely the most secure and up-to-date, configurations.

In your original code snippet, you do specify secrets by their names (without versions): `"notification_email"` and `"notification_password"`.

```js
exports.onUserCreate = onDocumentCreated(
  {
    memory: "1GiB",
    document: "users/{id}",
    secrets: ["notification_email", "notification_password"],
  },
  async (event) => {
    //...
  }
)
```

In the absence of a version specifier, the cloud provider's deployment process will bind the latest version of the secret to the function at the time of deployment.

If your Firebase Function is referring to an outdated secret version, it could be due to:

1. the function was deployed with a specific version of the secret, which you have said is not the case since there is no version parameter in your function definition.
2. the function has not been redeployed after the secret was updated. Firebase Functions do not automatically pick up changes in Secret Manager; you need to redeploy the function to use the latest version of the environment secrets.

In your Cloud Function, you can add temporary logging to inspect the environment variables and confirm that they hold the expected values.

```js
exports.onUserCreate = onDocumentCreated(
  {
    memory: "1GiB",
    document: "users/{id}",
    secrets: ["notification_email", "notification_password"],
  },
  async (event) => {
    console.log(process.env.NOTIFICATION_EMAIL);
    console.log(process.env.NOTIFICATION_PASSWORD);
    //...
  }
);
```

If you are experiencing this issue in a local development environment, make sure to restart your local emulator or any local servers after updating the secrets. Local environments might cache environment variables and require a restart to pick up changes.

If your function still does not use the latest version of the secrets after redeploying, it could be a bug or a limitation within Firebase Functions (2nd gen), as it [was reported before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76905961/6309).

Comment: Very well explained